# An error is occurring when get text from cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new in Cypress Automation.

Here is html code to Get get text from cypress. Here is Kendo UI dropdown

```
<input kendo-date-time-picker="" kendo-date-now-link=""
   id="createPlantsDateTime" name="createPlantsDateTime" ng-model="$ctrl.timestamp"
   ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled('group')"
   k-options="$ctrl.timepickerOpts" class="ng-valid ng-isolate-scope
   k-input ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"
   data-role="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" type="text"
   role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" autocomplete="off" xpath="1">
```

Here is my code:

```
Grow_GetCreatePlantDateandTime()
{
    return cy.xpath("//input[@id='createPlantsDateTime']")
}
     

element1.Grow_GetCreatePlantDateandTime(`enter code here`).should((gettime) =>
{
    const time =gettime.text()
     cy.log(time)
})
```

but here, I got error is

> Cannot read property 'text' of null.

How can I get the date on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are few basic mistakes in a code you are trying.
`Grow_GetCreatePlantDateandTime` function doesn't have any parameters in its signature and you are passing `code` as an argument.

Also, I am not sure whether `text()` will return the value.

However, if you want to grab the text from the field, you can try the below options.

```
let getTime;
cy.xpath("//input[@id='createPlantsDateTime']").invoke('text').then(time => {
    getTime = time;
});
```

OR

```
let getTime;
cy.xpath("//input[@id='createPlantsDateTime']").invoke('val').then(time => {
    getTime = time;
});
```